# Should locking occur at API layer, application layer, or both?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

As an API designer, does it make sense to perform lock checks to ensure that the object state is not invalidated by the caller?

Consider a `Grid3D` data structure which must resize itself each time its `Width`, `Heigth`, or `Depth` is changed.  If a caller is modifying the `Grid3D` from multiple threads, the `Grid` could be resizing while a new resize attempt is made and this would invalidate the object state or throw an exception.

This can be overcome by using locks to provide mutual exclusion to the resize function, and it could happen either within the API (that is, the class definition of `Grid3D`) or it can happen in the application where `Grid3D` is used.

If it is correct to lock inside the `Grid3D` class definition, it stands to say that thread synchronization should be considered for all API development. In many cases (certainly many examples online including StackOverflow) do not consider synchronization in API-level classes.

*So, where is the correct place to perform locking?  Under what conditions should the API-level be concerned with locking?*

Comment: Strange, this topic is too broad and actually I am missing any details. So we can actually answer on this in 20 different ways and they will all be correct. It is like asking, whether tomorrow will be nice and shiny day, not specifying any location:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your design decision, You can create a thread safe class or you can delegate the task of using it in thread safe manner to the one who uses it.

Usually libraries does not provide thread safe instances of classes when they are not intended to be used in multi-threaded environment. If the main usage of your class is in multi-threaded environment you should handle the thread-safety.

You can see this quote million of times in MSDN

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

this means that instances of the class are not meant to be used by default in multi-thread environment but you [can see also classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx) that support built in synchronization by default and are ready to be used in multi-threaded environment.

As I see the `Grid3D` is meant to be a UI component and usually UI components are built to be used just by the thread that have created them.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether the API is supposed to be thread-safe or not. If it is, then API layer should be concerned with locking, otherwise it should not.

As an example have a look at `System.Threading.Thread` and `System.Array` classes. The `Thread` is thread-safe and it is documented so (see Thread Safety section), while `Array` is not thread-safe and it is noted in documentation that its “…Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe”.